# Create a private network between virtual machines running in multiple hosts using Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to create a private network between virtual machines running in multiple hosts using Virtualbox. Linux will be used as guest operating system, and Windows in the hosts.

How do I set this up using Virtualbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1: Hardware**

- Purchase a dedicated NIC for each machine (or use VLANs if your NICs support them).
- Attach these NIC to the virtual machines only
- Connect these NICs together with an isolated physical switch or use VLANs on your switch if it is supported

This should give you a private network between hosts

**Option 2: Software**

- Configure an OpenVPN server on a guest VM
- Have each Linux machine VPN to the OpenVPN server on a network that only exists on the OpenVPN guest VM

By connecting the machines using virtual private networking, you should be able to create a private LAN that only those machines exist on.

Answer (score 1):

[Logmein Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/vpn.asp) is a free VPN solution which supports Windows, Linux and OS X. Quite easy to install. It may be a little "overpowered" for your situation but should work.

Edit: Another, similar option is [wippien.com](http://wippien.com/), look at their "[Mini Wippien](http://wippien.com/minivpn.php)" option. Quote: "Unlike Wippien that combines two worlds together, miniVPN is small appliation that will give you benefit of having VPN without instant messaging capabilities."

Comment: Here is the [list of alternative apps](http://serverfault.com/a/746572/100769) for F2F / P2PVPN.

Answer (score 0):

If the host machines are all on the same network, you may be able to configure DHCP to assign the MAC addresses used by VirtualBox (or VMWare) VMs to a different 'virtual' network.

For example, say all your host machines run on 192.168.0.0.  You could configure DHCP to assign all computers with MAC addresses beginning with 80:00:27 to the 192.168.99.0 network.

Hope this helps.