# Create a fail-safe private network between multiple cloud servers

Tags: vpn, failover

I want to create a virtual private network between two or more virtual cloud servers, comparable to [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (Amazon VPC is not an option, as the servers are not hosted at AWS).

I have already found a [very similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/46884/create-a-private-network-between-virtual-machines-running-in-multiple-hosts-usin) regarding this problem, and while the second option of the [accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/46937/85014) -- hosting a OpenVPN-server on one of the machines and have the others connect -- is a good solution, I don't like the fact, that the private network depends on one server being up.

So, my question: Can I create a private network where the network does not depend on a single server?

(Suggestions similar to VLAN won't cut it for me, as I do not have physical access to the machines, and they might even be in different data centers).

Comment: _Something_ has to be up for you to have a network!

Comment: "Can I create a private network where the network does not depend on a single server?" : create an openvpn cluster, implement failover, or use more robust appliance vpn dedicated

Comment: @MichaelHampton The point is, if I have mulitple servers -- i.e. more than 2 -- and the one running the OpenVPN server fails, the other two or more servers would no longer share a private network. user2196728 Thanks for the keyword of OpenVPN cluster, I will look into it!

Comment: You can also have a look to keepalived on Linux to ensure failover